# How can I merge PHP files into one PHP file (not .phar)?

Tags: php

I have an index.php file that has these codes:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/asd1.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/asd2.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/asd3.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/asd4.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/asd5.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/asd6.php';
```

I want to "compile" the index.php from those `require_once`s into one PHP file. I want the result of the compilation to be in .php and not .phar.

Comment: If these are static files, why not do that using an editor and just merge these files?

Comment: No, I want to do it systematically. I can create the script to replace evert `require_once`s ofcourse. But, I am looking if an existing solution is already exists.

Comment: Do you really just need a way of including every file in a directory? Or is there a reason they need to be in a single file?

Comment: Whats wrong with what you have, that is basically doing what you suggest you want to do

Comment: When you say **compile** do you actually mean **amalgamate**

Comment: The "compiled" PHP file will be executed via CURL. Hence, it needs to be in one PHP file and not Phar.

Comment: I dont see why curl'ing to a php file would need you to change it in any way

Comment: Tell me how can I put PHP files into Gist and execute it from there, then.

Comment: And this is your first mention of Gist and why you think you want to do this :(

Comment: I don't get what you mean. My request is crystal clear. I want to combine PHP files into only one file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think your purpose is to do some preprocessing like C preprocessor, something, like search and replace string representing files inclusions by their contents so i write the code below but keep in mind that this code is not generic and may not fit other cases than the case you show here.Of course you can use it as a starting point to achieve other purpose.

```
function preprocessing($path,$tempname=false){
        $preprocessing=file($path);
        foreach($preprocessing as &$values){
            if(($x=strtolower(substr(($v=trim($values)),0,12)))=='require_once'||$x=='include_once'||substr($x,0,7)=='include'||substr($x,0,7)=='require'){
                if($u=strpos($v,'(')){
                    $temp=substr($v,$u,strpos($v,')'));
                    $temp=trim(file_get_contents(eval('return '.$temp.';')));
                    if($temp){
                        if(substr($temp,0,5)==='<?php') 
                            $temp=substr($temp,6);
                        if(substr($temp,0,2)==='<?') 
                            $temp=substr($temp,3);
                        if(substr($temp,-2)==='?>')
                            $temp=substr($temp,0,-3);
                        $values=$temp;
                    }
                    unset($temp);
                }else{
                    $temp=explode(' ',trim($v,';'));
                    $temp=trim(file_get_contents(eval('return '.end($temp).';')));
                    if($temp){
                        if(substr($temp,0,5)==='<?php') 
                            $temp=substr($temp,6);
                        if(substr($temp,0,2)==='<?') 
                            $temp=substr($temp,3);
                        if(substr($temp,-2)==='?>')
                            $temp=substr($temp,0,-3);
                        $values=$temp;
                    }
                    unset($temp);
                }
            }
        }
        if(!$tempname) 
            $tempname=uniqid().'.php';
        file_put_contents($tempname, implode('',$preprocessing));



        return $tempname;
    }

    function recursive_preprocessing($path){
        $tempname=uniqid().'.php';
        file_put_contents($tempname,'');
        $i=0;
        do{
            $hash=sha1_file($tempname);
            if($i==0)
                $tempname=preprocessing($path,$tempname);
            else
                $tempname=preprocessing($tempname,$tempname);
            $i++;

        }while(sha1_file($tempname)!==$hash&&preg_match('#require|require_once|include|include_once#i',file_get_contents($tempname) ));
        return $tempname;
    }

    print(recursive_preprocessing('index.php'));
```

the first function is really simple.It takes the path to the main file and generate a new  file as expected and then return the path to this new file .In this test i just print the new path to the screen to find the new file .

the second function use the first function to replace recursively all inclusions and then return the path to the final file.
keep in mind that at this state ,only resolved filenames can be replaced by their contents.If for any reason the preprocessing function can't get the contents of a file the inclusion statement will not be replaced.

Comment: I'll check this out as soon as I have access to my computer. This seems what I need.